# How to display zero as count if there is no record in data base(oracle) in combination with Date column using spring jpa?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

I want to query for the transaction count of the column values in a table by hour for the current day because I want to show these count in graph.

I'm having trouble displaying results even for the hours with no records in that case I should print 0 count, I have tried with

```sql
with tmpTable as 
(
    select 
        (minHourSeq + level-1) hourSeq 
    from 
        (select 
             min(extract (hour from TXN_DATE_TIME)) minHourSeq, 
             max(extract (hour from TXN_DATE_TIME)) maxHourSeq 
         from 
             TRANSACTION_REQUEST) v 
    connect by 
        (minHourSeq + level-1) <= maxHourSeq
)
select 
    a.hourSeq as hour, nvl(count(b.transaction), 0) as count 
from 
    TRANSACTION_REQUEST b, tmpTable a 
where 
    a.hourSeq = extract(hour from b.TXN_DATE_TIME(+)) 
group by 
    a.hourSeq 
order by 
    1;
```

It's working while I'm executing it in Oracle SQL developer, but I'm getting an error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

while trying to implement with my code

```java
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                "with tmpTable as (select (minHourSeq + level-1) hourSeq from (select min(extract (hour from txnDate)) minHourSeq, max(extract (hour from txnDate)) maxHourSeq from "
                        + TransactionRequest.class.getName()
                        + " ) v connect by (minHourSeq + level-1) <= maxHourSeq) "
                        + "select a.hourSeq as hour,nvl(count(b.transaction),0) as count from "
                        + TransactionRequest.class.getName()
                        + " b,tmpTable a a.hourSeq = extract(hour from b.txnDate(+)) group by a.hourSeq order by 1");
```

Comment: any other solution will also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

"Other solution" might be moving the CTE into an inline view; maybe tool you use doesn't recognize it. Something like this:

```
  SELECT a.hourSeq AS hour, NVL (COUNT (b.transaction), 0) AS COUNT
    FROM TRANSACTION_REQUEST b,
         -- WITH factoring clause moved into an inline view
         (    SELECT (minHourSeq + LEVEL - 1) hourSeq
                FROM (SELECT MIN (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM TXN_DATE_TIME)) minHourSeq,
                             MAX (EXTRACT (HOUR FROM TXN_DATE_TIME)) maxHourSeq
                        FROM TRANSACTION_REQUEST) v
          CONNECT BY (minHourSeq + LEVEL - 1) <= maxHourSeq) a
   WHERE a.hourSeq = EXTRACT (HOUR FROM b.TXN_DATE_TIME(+))
GROUP BY a.hourSeq
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Sorry to late reply, now getting "SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 0):

You missed `where` in value of `query`, Use this:

```java
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
                "with tmpTable as (select (minHourSeq + level-1) hourSeq from (select min(extract (hour from txnDate)) minHourSeq, max(extract (hour from txnDate)) maxHourSeq from "
                        + TransactionRequest.class.getName()
                        + " ) v connect by (minHourSeq + level-1) <= maxHourSeq) "
                        + "select a.hourSeq as hour,nvl(count(b.transaction),0) as count from "
                        + TransactionRequest.class.getName()
                        + " b,tmpTable a where a.hourSeq = extract(hour from b.txnDate(+)) group by a.hourSeq order by 1");
```

Comment: sorry to late reply, yes I missed where while I was posting my query but problem is still same